# Problema ao clicar ao um Objecto no jogo de reflexos em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Boas,
Estou com um problema quando clico no objecto (ex:quadrado, ou circulo), ele devia outro objecto em outro ponto entre as margens. eu tenho uma variável var top e var left que definem o tamanho das margens no script javascript dentro da função randomShape(){} para quando o objecto for cliclado ele gera outro objecto num sitio diferente.

Este é o código do Javascript.

```
    var clickedTime, createTime, reactionTime;

function randomShape() {
  var color = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
  var codColor;

  codColor = Math.random();
  codColor = codColor * 4;
  codColor = Math.floor(codColor);
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.backgroundColor = color[codColor];

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("divbox").style.borderRadius = "100px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divbox").style.borderRadius = "0";
  }

  var top = Math.random();
  top = top * 500;
  var left = Math.random();
  left = left * 800;

  document.getElementById("divbox").style.top = top + "px";
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.left = left + "px";
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Ajuda bastante se colocar o código aqui e não em outro lugar. Ajuda mais ainda se ler os *links* acima.

Comment: @Maniero já retirei os links e pus o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou atribuir o posicionamento do seu elemento. Por padrão, o posicionamento de todo elemento é `static`, o que significa que ele simplesmente irá se alinhar com o elemento pai ignorando as posições definidas em `top`, `bottom`, `left` e `right`.

Para poder definir a posição do seu elemento você precisa de um posicionamento do tipo `relative`, `fixed` ou `absolute`. Para este caso, você poderia utilizar `absolute` por exemplo, para posicionar seu `divbox` relativo a uma viewport, como o seu `divgame`, que por sua vez precisa ter o posicionamento `relative` para ser utilizado como referência.

```js
var clickedTime, createTime, reactionTime;

function randomShape() {
  var color = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
  var codColor;

  codColor = Math.random();
  codColor = codColor * 4;
  codColor = Math.floor(codColor);
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.backgroundColor = color[codColor];

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("divbox").style.borderRadius = "100px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divbox").style.borderRadius = "0";
  }

  var top = Math.random();
  top = top * 300; //500px - 200px
  var left = Math.random();
  left = left * 600; //800px - 200px

  document.getElementById("divbox").style.top = top + "px";
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.left = left + "px";
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.display = "block";
}

function makeBox() {
   createTime = Date.now();
  setTimeout(showDisplay, 3000);
  randomShape();
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.display = "block";

}

function showDisplay() {
  var time = Math.random();
  time = time * 3000;
  time;
}

document.getElementById("divbox").onclick = function () {
  clickedTime = Date.now();
  reactionTime = (clickedTime - createTime) / 1000;
  if(reactionTime > 0.100){
  document.getElementById("reactionTime").innerHTML = reactionTime + " seconds";
  }else{
    alert("Parabéns! Novo Recorde!");
    document.getElementById("recordTime").innerHTML = reactionTime;
  }
  document.getElementById("divbox").style.display = "none";
  makeBox();
}

makeBox();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Javascript - Exercício 5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
    #divbox {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:blue;
        display:none;
        position:relative;
    }
    #divgame {
        width:800px;
        height:500px;
        border:2px black solid;
        margin:auto;
        position:absolute;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Jogo - Tempo de reação</h1>

   <h2>Record: <span id="recordTime"><span></h2>
   <p>Tempo de reação: <span id="reactionTime"><span></p>
   <div id="divgame">
   <div id="divbox"></div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado @user140828